# Hive exception java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassCastException:

Tags: hadoop, hive

My Hive (version 0.14.0.2.2.6.4-1) table `table_test` is in `ORC` format with some data, I needed to re-structure that table

1. I have taken a backup table (`ORC` format) using

   ```
   create table table_test_bk as select * from table_test;
   ```
2. Drop Original table as:

   ```
   drop table table_test;
   ```
3. Running the modified DDL for table_test re-creation (with a new column in the middle column_new string)

   The old table struncture:

   ```
   (col1 string,col2 decimal(10,2),col3 timestamp);
   ```

   The new table struncture:

   ```
   (col1 string,col2 decimal(10,2),column_new string,col3 timestamp);
   ```
4. Restoring the data-set from backup table using

   ```
   insert into table table_test select col1,col2,null as column_new,col3 from table_test_bk;
   ```
5. When step 4 runs successfully, dropping up the backup table

All these 5 steps ran successfully, but while doing data-sanity I can see the below exception, and I am unable to get any o/p. Where as doing `select count(1) from table_test;` is giving me proper data-count.

> Failed with exception java.io.IOException:org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.io.HiveDecimalWritable cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.io.Text

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I have seen other kinds of **bugs** with Null values in ORC format. And with Hive 0.14 I would have expected the `null as column_new` part to fail because of Hive not knowing implicitly which kind of Null to cast (to be replaced with ``cast(null as decimal(10,2)``)  ==> good luck with that one :-/

Comment: @Samson: That helped. it was a casting error. Thank you Samson :-)