# ALTER TABLE ADD COLUMN WITH DEFAULT NULL

Tags: java, hive, mapreduce, hiveddl

I have a table Facility header and i want to alter it and add few columns.I want the newly added  columns to hold default value as null. My table is already  loaded with 14 years of data .As it is partitioned table for year 2002-2014 by default the value of these newly added column should come null in the table .

```
create table facility_HEADER
(
A string,
B INT,
C INT
)partitioned by (year int comment 'Date Year Incurred') 
STORED AS PARQUET
```

**Alter Table Command**

```
ALTER TABLE facility_HEADER add columns (MSCLMID Bigint,NPI STRING,UNITS decimal(10,2));
```

When i put a describe on the table i can see the columns got appended at the end .
When i put a select * from any of the partition it gives error.

> Failed with exception
> java.io.IOException:org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException:
> java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable cannot
> be cast to org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable

My table is having 14 years of data and i don't want it to be done with putting null into select clause and giving aliases.

I tried the things referring from [here](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-6-x/topics/impala_alter_table.html) and from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31936665/hive-exception-java-lang-runtimeexception-java-lang-classcastexception).

Can any one help me what actually happened with my table .I lost 14 years of data in a go.

Answer (score 0):

Make a full files backup first. Try to alter table and drop newly added columns. If you didn't write into table yet, it should work. Check the table is selectable again.  Then create new table with new columns and insert overwrite into.

Answer (score 0):

Using alter command on hive it just changed metadata not under laying data so while select * from table will fail.

As hive is trying to extract data from file stored "/apps/hive/warehouse/databasename.db/tablename/" using using **row_format and file_format** it will not able to find column values as described on row_format  .

**Note** : Data is STORED AS PARQUET hive is not getting definition of new column on PARQUET

work around: create new table and insert data and rename table as oldtablname

INSERT INTO TABLE 
 selet columns(old) null as MSCLMID ,null as NPI, null as UNITS  from oldtabel

Comment: I already  mentioned in my query I do not want to put select and null as those columns as my data is in TBs another insert  command will cause me more time .Is there other workaround ??

Comment: that is why i told only work around no another option unless you change your parquet files...